# cannot capture NumberFormatException in a unit test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

i have a unit test which have to fail at purpose, but I cannot capture it, so it is weird.

This is how it looks the csv file:

```
curva;clase;divisa;rw
AED_FXDEP;OIS;AED;240,1000
ARS :Std;6m;ARS;240
AUD_CALMNY_DISC;OIS;AUD;169.7056275
AUD_DEPO_BBSW;6m;AUD;169.7056275
AUD_DEPO_BBSW;6m;AUD;
```

And this is the content of the json schema file:

```
{"type" : "struct","fields" : [ {"name" : "curve","type" : "string","nullable" : false}, {"name":"class", "type":"string", "nullable":false}, {"name":"currency", "type":"string", "nullable":false}, {"name":"rw", "type":"string","nullable":false} ]
```

I think it is self explainable, the last line of the csv has an empty field and that is not permitted, the exception is clear, NumberFormatException because you can create a number with an empty value. I want to catch the exception in the unit test, why I can't reach it?

This is the code that provokes the exception:

```
try{
    val validateGenericFile : Boolean = CSVtoParquet.validateGenericCSV(pathCSVWithHeaderWithErrors,
                                                                      pathCurvasJsonSchemaWithDecimal,
                                                                      _nullValue,
                                                                      _delimiter,
                                                                      sc,
                                                                      sqlContext)
    //never reach!
    Assert.assertTrue(validateGenericFile)
} catch {
    case e:NumberFormatException => Assert.assertTrue("ERROR! " + e.getLocalizedMessage,false)
    case ex:Exception => Assert.assertTrue("ERROR! " + ex.getLocalizedMessage,false)
} finally {
    println("Done testValidateInputFilesFRTBSTDES436_WithErrors!")
}
```

the method validateGenericCSV looks like:

```
val myDfWithCustomSchema = _sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
                                            option("header", "true").
                                            option("delimiter", _delimiter).
                                            option("nullValue", _nullValue).
                                            option("mode","FAILFAST").
                                            schema(mySchemaStructType).
                                            load(fileToReview)

var finallyCorrect : Boolean = true

var contLinesProcessed = 1

try{
  //this line provokes the exception!
  val myArray = myDfWithCustomSchema.collect


  var contElementosJson = 0

  var isTheLineCorrect: Boolean = true


  myArray.foreach { elem =>
    println("Processing line with content: " + elem)
    for (myElem <- myList) {
      val actualType = myElem.`type`
      val actualName = myElem.name
      val actualNullable = myElem.nullable

      if (contElementosJson == myList.size) {
        contElementosJson = 0
      }

      if (actualType == "string") {
        val theField = elem.getString(contElementosJson)
        val validatingField: Boolean = theField.isInstanceOf[String]

        isTheLineCorrect = validatingField && !((theField == "" || theField == null) && !actualNullable)
        contElementosJson += 1
        if (!isTheLineCorrect){
          finallyCorrect=false
          println("ATTENTION! an empty string chain. " + "Check this field " + actualName + " in the csv file, which should be a " + actualType + " according with the json schema file, can be nullable? " + actualNullable + " isTheLineCorrect? " + isTheLineCorrect)
        }
      } else if (actualType == "integer") {
        val theField = elem.get(contElementosJson)
        val validatingField: Boolean = theField.isInstanceOf[Integer]
        isTheLineCorrect = validatingField && !((theField == "" || theField == null) && !actualNullable)
        contElementosJson += 1
        if (!isTheLineCorrect){
          finallyCorrect=false
          println("ATTENTION! an empty string chain. " + "Check this field " + actualName + " in the csv file, which should be a " + actualType + " according with the json schema file, can be nullable? " + actualNullable + " isTheLineCorrect? " + isTheLineCorrect)
        }
      } else if (actualType.startsWith("decimal")) {
        val theField = elem.get(contElementosJson)
        val validatingField: Boolean = theField.isInstanceOf[java.math.BigDecimal]
        isTheLineCorrect = validatingField && !((theField == "" || theField == null) && !actualNullable)
        contElementosJson += 1
        if (!isTheLineCorrect){
          finallyCorrect=false
          println("ATTENTION! an empty string chain. " + "Check this field " + actualName + " in the csv file, which should be a " + actualType + " according with the json schema file, can be nullable? " + actualNullable + " isTheLineCorrect? " + isTheLineCorrect)
        }
      } else {
        println("Attention! se está intentando procesar una columna del tipo " + actualType + " que no está prevista procesar. Comprobar.")
      }
    } //for
    contLinesProcessed += 1
  } //foreach))

} catch {
  //NEVER REACHED! why????
  case e:NumberFormatException => throw e
  case ex:Exception => throw ex
}
```

Why the NumberFormatException is never reached within in validateGenericCSV method?

UPDATE

i have modified these lines:

```
case e:NumberFormatException => Assert.assertTrue("ERROR! " + e.getLocalizedMessage,true)
case ex:Exception => Assert.assertTrue("ERROR! " + ex.getLocalizedMessage,true)
```

for these lines:

```
case e:NumberFormatException => Assert.assertTrue("ERROR! " + e.getLocalizedMessage,false)
case ex:Exception => Assert.assertTrue("ERROR! " + ex.getLocalizedMessage,false)
```

The same error, my problem is that I cannot reach to the catch sentences when the exception happens!

Thank you

Comment: could you show the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Hi @maasg, http://pastebin.com/X2KFZiJ5

Comment: btw, do you realize that by doing `val myArray = myDfWithCustomSchema.collect` you are bringing all data to the driver? That will only work for data files that can fit in the memory of the Spark driver. I guess that's OK in the context of an Unit test, but should not be used as a general approach.

Comment: I know that i am collecting very few data, i can afford it, but i would like not to have to collect in a general approach, thank you for the answer @maag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting the stack trace, we can see the following:

> ERROR! Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException

Spark is a distributed computing framework. The `NumberFormatException` is taking place *remotely* at one of the executors while processing a task. Spark gets a `TaskFailure` from that executor and propagates the exception wrapped in a `org.apache.spark.SparkException` to the action that triggered the materialization of the computation: the `.collect()` method in this specific case.

If we would like to get the reason behind the failure, we can use `ex.getCause`. 
In practical terms we will have something like this snippet:

```
catch {
  case ex:Exception if ex.getCause.getClass == classOf[NumberFormatException] => Assert.fail("Number parsing failed" + e.getLocalizedMessage)
  case ex:Exception => Assert.fail(...)
}
```

Comment: hum, thank you for the answer @maasg, so, ¿can't I arise the exception up?

Comment: @aironman I thought that the intention was to recognize the reason of the failure. That can be done by inspecting the `cause` as shown. I'm not sure what do you mean with "arise the exception up"

Comment: sorry, @maasg, my poor English, what I would like to have is to detect the exception and rise up it to the caller in order that this caller treats with the exception. I would like to throw it up doing catch {
  case ex:Exception if ex.getCause.getClass == classOf[NumberFormatException] => throw ex
  case ex:Exception => Assert.fail(...)
}

Comment: @aironman sure it is possible: `throw ex.getCause`. but why do you propagate those exceptions in a unit test? btw your English is fine.

Comment: hi @maasg, the answer is I like to test code to find weak points and try to have a code as robust as possible. I will try your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The test won't fail because `Assert.assertTrue(...,true)` does not fail. `assertTrue` fails if the second parameter is `false` but not when it's `true`.

Comment: Hi @Simon, thanks for the answer but no, the problem, I think, is that the exception is never thrown up, so I never can assert.